How to create a custom block template for a specific region in Drupal 11?
I'm working with Drupal 11 and have a region on my homepage called "frontrow1" that contains several blocks. I have created a subtheme of Bootstrap 5.
In Drupal 7, I was able to create a template for blocks in that region using block--frontrow1.tpl.php, but I can't seem to create a similar template in Drupal 11 using block--frontrow1.html.twig.
I've tried to check for the region in block.html.twig by adding the region parameter in hook_preprocess_block(), but I wasn't successful in getting it to work.
/**
Implements hook_preprocess_block().
*/
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(array &$variables) {
//Check if the block is inside a region on the page.
if (isset($variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'])) {
     $variables['region'] = $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'];
else {
     $variables['region'] = NULL;
   }
}

Despite this, I'm still unable to get the block region information properly within the template.
{{ region }} //outputs NULL

How can I create a custom layout for blocks specifically in the "frontrow1" region? Any guidance on the correct approach for templating this case in Drupal 11 would be greatly appreciated!

I was able to add the region variable to my block using a different approach. So I can now handle it in block.html.twig. This is a solution for me. But I’m still curious if there is a way to use regions in the namespace of the templates.
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    if (isset($variables["elements"]["#id"])) {
        $block_id = $variables["elements"]["#id"];
        $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);

        if ($block) {
            $variables["region"] = $block->getRegion();
        }
    }

}

